# Consolidate two tables awk

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have two files (all tab delimited):

`database.txt`

```
MAR001;string1;H
MAR002;string2;G
MAR003;string3;H
```

`data.txt`

```
data1;MAR002
data2;MAR003
```

And I want to consolidate these two tables using the `MAR###` column. Expected output (tab-delimited):

```
data1;MAR002;string2;G
data2;MAR003;string3;H
```

I want to use awk; this is my attempt:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} FNR == NR { a[$2] = $1; next } $2 in a { print $0, a[$1] }' data.txt database.txt
```

but this fails...

Comment: you think `;`  and `\t` are same thing?

Comment: No, but I cannot type tabs here so I used semicolons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 awk -F '\t' 'FNR==1 && NR == 1 { strt=1 } FNR==1 && NR != 1 { strt=0} strt==1 {dat[$1]=$2";"$3 } strt==0 { if ( dat[$2] != "" ) { print $1";"$2";"dat[$2] } }' database.txt data.txt
```

Read database.txt in first and read the data into an array dat. Then when we encounter the data.txt file, check for entries in the dat array and print the required data if there is one.

Output:

```
data1;MAR002;string2;G
data2;MAR003;string3;H
```

Comment: When I do this with my sample input here it works, but with my full data it does not...? Any ideas on how to find out why?

Comment: `data.txt` maybe not; the file is big so I cannot guarantee

Comment: ok this does not work. you can access the full database file here: http://eggnogdb.embl.de/download/eggnog_4.0/description/NOG.description.txt.gz (it is not MAR but COG - the change in my input file was intended; I am searching COG against COG of course)

Comment: It's delimited by tab, are both files like this? There is no third piece of data

Comment: yes, all files are tab-delimited in reality (my input here is with ; because I cannot put TABS as single chars in stack)

Comment: OK, I've changed the solution to use tabs. Give that a go.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150757/discussion-between-tobi-and-raman-sailopal).

Answer (score 4):

I would just use the `join` command. It's very easy:

```
join -t \; -1 1 -2 2 database.txt data.txt
MAR002;string2;G;data1
MAR003;string3;H;data2
```

You can specify output column order using `-o`. For example:

```
join -t \; -1 1 -2 2 -o 2.1,2.2,1.2,1.3 database.txt data.txt
data1;MAR002;string2;G
data2;MAR003;string3;H
```

P.S. I did assume your files are "semicolon separated" and not "tab separated". Also, your files need to be sorted by the key column.

Answer (score 0):

First of all `;` and `\t` are different characters. If your real input files are tab delimited, here is the fix on your codes:

Change your codes into:

```
awk '....... $1 in a { print a[$1], $0 }' data.txt database.txt
```